# Can't find WebKit framework in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I downloaded xcode a month ago. AnD I am trying to add `webkit` framework to use it in iOS development. It isn't listed with the other framework.  Do I have to download it manually? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Webkit.framework in Cocoa Touch. The webkit framework is only available on OS X. For iOS, just use UIWebview.

For more info, look here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Essentially though this is very easy. Just add a UIWebview in your .h, connect it to your webview in your Storyboard. Also, in your .h, add the UIWebview delegate.

Something like:

`@interface yourViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>`

Then, in the .m, use

`[webView setDelegate:self];` Probably in your viewDidLoad method.

Good luck!